# I am trying to add onclick event to dynamically generated html tags into the UI, I am using angular 2

Tags: jquery, typescript, angular, onclick, dynamic-html

here is my code..

```
<i id="lrbp" #lrbp data-toggle="popover" [attr.data-content]="popovercontent" data-placement="bottom" (click)="openSettingPopOver(lrbp)" class="btn btn-default fa fa-cog fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

the data-content will be generated in .ts file, eg.

```
initPopOverContent(){
    this.popovercontent = "<ul class='list-group' style='margin:0'>" +
        "<li type='button' (click)='draw3D()' class='list-group-item'><i class='fa fa-cubes' aria-hidden='true'></i> 3D Chart</li>" +
        "<li type='button' class='list-group-item'><i class='fa fa-line-chart' aria-hidden='true'></i> Line Chart</li>" +
        "<li type='button' class='list-group-item'><i class='fa fa-pie-chart' aria-hidden='true'></i> Pie Chart</li>" +
        "</ul>";    
}

openSettingPopOver(id: any) {
    this.popover = id;
    let template: string = '<div class="popover" style="min-width:10em" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content" style="padding:0"></div></div>';

    $(id).popover({ html: true, template: template }).popover('toggle');
}
```

but the on click event

> **(click)='draw3D()'** *this function is in the same .ts file*

is not getting called.

I know the reason could be the improper way of attaching html tags in angular 2 dynamically.

could anyone help me if they have solved a similar kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported. Dynamically added HTML is just passed along to the browser and sanitized (stripped by potential dangerous HTML,CSS, ...) but no Angular2 bindings or components and directives are created.